# QGIS - Export selected records in attribute of specific layer to a CSV file with Python Script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I want to create a script to export selected attributes from a specific layer to a CSV file, this is a continued routine and is slow by using the export button. Where would i need to start with this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this: (make sure you have selected some attributes before running the script)

```py
import csv
    
path_to_your_csv_file = 'C:/Users/Users/Documents/test.csv'
    
layer = iface.activeLayer()
    
# opening the csv file with the writing mode on:
csv_file = open(path_to_your_csv_file, 'w', encoding = 'latin-1')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    
features = layer.selectedFeatures()
    
for f in features:
    writer.writerow([f["field1"], f["field2"]])
    
csv_file.close()
```